# php Script runs fast in a browser, but very slow locally

Tags: php, performance, browser, local

I have seen a few answers to the opposite problem, but not the one I am experiencing.

I have a couple of scripts which connects to SQL, and run select queries to populate an XML file which uploads to an FTP at the end. They all seem to be running much slower now that I am trying to run them locally from command line when compared to when I was just running them from a browser.

The scripts could take 30 seconds in a browser, and now they could take over an hour when running them locally. I am sure it isn't the most efficient bit of php programming, but that isn't the issue here.

fyi, I run Apache locally from XAMPP on my computer. EDIT: The 'browser' means running it off my server (another machine).

I am not terribly IT savvy, so if there is a beginner explanation, that would be super helpful.

Comment: php scripts run on a server.

Comment: @Dagon "_locally from command line_"

Comment: When running them from the CLI, how are you doing that? I ask because you mention Apache via XAMPP, which which wouldn't come into play from normal CLI execution.

Comment: im not nitpicking but choice of language is important when asking a technical question.

Comment: is the cli php version the same as that "run in the browser", you could have 2 versions, there own settigns and configurations

Comment: Did you check if there is firewall or something that holds the command-line script from being executed normally. You should try the same script on a couple of other machines, perhaps your computer have some restriction for executable programs, since you run from cmd window, its most likely considered and bound to the rules of a dos program by firewalls.

Comment: My guess is that on the commandline you have another php.ini. My guess is also that you use a third-party tool to generate the XML, one that will fallback to the php-extension when it is loaded. My guess is also that it's not loaded and runs on the third-party code rather than the php-extension. I could be wrong ofc, but it's just a guess.

Comment: @Dragon I use XAMPP for windows and it uses the same configurations for both browser based as well as CLI. The CLI output is pure text while the browser output is rendered HTML.  CLI comes handy if there is less to do with HTML and more to do with Code.  Also CLI do not have timeout's , that simply means CLI can run for hours together like a normal program.

Comment: I should have mentioned I did not have any 3rd party programs, and that by cli, I mean the one on my computer (not SSH or on the server) @Dagon I will check to see if my php on the server (5.3.3) is the same as what I have on my computer. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Where is the SQL database, local or on your server? Where is the FTP location, local or on your server? When you run it via the command line, are you definitely on your local machine and not SSH'd in to your server? When you run it through the browser, are you sure it's going to your server and not your local machine?

Comment: This is not a hardware problem. I have the same problem, at first I thought it was because I had multiple sites hosted locally but I removed many of them and it is still slow. Furthermore I checked and all local resources (cpu, ram, io and net) were very low.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

locally mean your computer , browser mean your server , server faster than your computer so that is normal

Comment: most peoples web hosts are (much)slower than there own pc's

Comment: You can also have a server running on your own PC. You can also be on an ssh connection to the server and "locally" run the same script on the server.

Comment: ask him about his pc ram and cpu and about his server , that is a problem i think

Comment: @urorbit there is no scope of ram and other physical things if both the server and CLI runs on the same computer. In this case I assume its the same, while there is no input from the questioner if its the same.

Comment: @urorbit This is a simple explanation, which makes sense. My server is a 6-core 2.3gHz w/ 16 GB RAM, compared to my computer which is 2.3GHz single core 4GB running other things at the same time. I will look into the ideas listed above, but perhaps hardware is the answer. Thank you.